# Vertical align responsive container in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertical align a container div within a jumbotron.

Because the height of the container (and so the jumbotron also) is variable `top: 50%; margin-top: -'height * 0.5'` won't work.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 .banner {
  padding: 48px 0px 48px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.banner:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 12.5%;
}

  .container {
  background: red !important; /* For testing vertical alignment */
  }
```

```html
<header class="jumbotron banner">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <p>Subtitle</p>
    <p> <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button</a>

    </p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/honawo/quiet ... 5 ways to do it, pick one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically Align text in a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should just center it using padding, this is the [default way](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/) of doing it;

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 .banner {
  padding: 5% 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.banner:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  
}

  .container {
  background: red !important; /* For testing vertical alignment */
  }
```

```html
<header class="jumbotron banner">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <p>Subtitle</p>
    <p> <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button</a>

    </p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This won't work. As I said the height of the banner should be variable.

Comment: in this way #banner will always adjust to .container adding padding top & bottom , from your question that's what I understand..

Comment: By changing the padding to percent the height becomes variable.

Comment: If you edit your post I can up vote it. `padding: 5% 0px 5% 0px;`

Answer (score 1):

To align div vertically center you can use css like

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translatey(-50%);
```

ex

```css
.outer{
    height:100px;
    background:gray;
}
.inner{
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translatey(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner" >
                  <p>sample text</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What position do i give to the parent?

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways you can get content aligned vertically. I am posting here one common and most recent trick.

1. Give `position: relative;` to the parent element.
2. To the child:

   .child-element {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   }

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/getanwar/bmb1nkdg/) and comment below if you need further assistance.

Comment: Your example is making things even worse.

Comment: Did you see JSFIDDLE which is working perfectly. Or maybe I was unable to understand what the question is?

Comment: Oh mey be you forgot to add `-webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, -o-` to the `transform` property to get cross browser compatibility! Please see my fiddle again [here](http://jsfiddle.net/getanwar/bmb1nkdg/1/) .